# price range filter using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

```
public function fetch_price_range_ads($min,$max)
   {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('user_added_ads');
    $this->db->join('media_ads','media_ads.user_added_ads_id=user_added_ads.user_added_ads_id');
    $this->db->group_by('user_added_ads.user_added_ads_id');

   $this->db->where('user_added_ads.price >= ',$min);
   $this->db->where('user_added_ads.price <=', $max);
    $q=$this->db->get();
    return $q->result();
    }
```

this is my model page,everything is working fine,but the thing is if $min=1200 and $max=1500,it fetching all the data whose price range starts starts from 1200 and 1500,
Ex apple=12010;

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$this->db->where("user_added_ads.price BETWEEN $min AND $max");
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried it, but its also no use,,anyhow thanks and i got my answer,,

```
in controller
         $min=$_POST['minimum'];
          $max=$_POST['maximum'];

          $mins = ( int ) str_replace( ',', '', $min );
          $maxs = ( int ) str_replace( ',', '', $max ); 
        $data['price_range']=$this->mymodel->fetch_price_range_ads($mins,$maxs);
```

this will work